# How do I configure Simple Backend in Django Registration

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I need to know how to pass a `success_url` to the simple backend in django-registration-1.0 that uses class based views.

Before 1.0 I used to have

```
from registration.views import register

url(r'^accounts/register/$', register, {'backend': 
'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend','form_class': RegistrationForm},     
 name='registration_register'),
```

I have changed it to be like this

```
from registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView

url(r'^accounts/register/$',  
RegistrationView.as_view(success_url=settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL), 
name='registration_register')
```

The back-end seems to work but the `success_url` is not getting picked up from the URLConf.

How do I fix this?

Update:

I have implemented by own `RegistrationView` sub-classing the Simple `RegistrationView` and overridden the `success_url` atleast as a temporary solution till I figure out something better

```
from registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView as SimpleRegistrationView

class RegistrationView(SimpleRegistrationView):
    def get_success_url(self, request, user):
        return (settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL, (), {})
```

Answer (score 1):

The code...

```
url(r'^accounts/register/$',
    RegistrationView.as_view(success_url=settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL),
    name='registration_register')
```

...is technically correct, but it looks like there's a bug in the django-registration library which means it will effectively ignore this value, so you'll have to override the `get_success_url()` method if you actually want something that works.